# Is compatible ffserver with drupal?

Tags: drupal, ffmpeg, ffserver

### ffmpeg the command line encoding tool but ffserver is a multimedia streaming server for live broadcasts. With it, you can stream over HTTP, RTP and RSTP.

first:
I used video module in drupal for convert videos and  play all.
In this module have a very configuration for use ffmpeg but not have any configuration for use ffserver.

second :
I used ffmpeg in a particular server , because have a very heavy process for converting video.

Now , i want know about this things:

1- is existing any module for use ffmpeg and ffserver in this.

2- if this module exist , is this correct to use ffmpeg and ffserver in a one server or i should Separate ffserver and ffmpeg server's.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could use the drupal module for the encoding.com API and automate your transcoding workflow in that fashion. Here is a link to the Drupal Module. https://www.drupal.org/project/encoding